# How to add images to database and then display them in datagridview using C#?

Tags: c#, database, image

I am using VS 2010 and have a database in C# with a column called 'Pic' that accepts images and is null.  Right now when I run my project the datagridview populates all the other columns but simple has a red X for my 'Pic' column.  My question is this; how can I code it so that pictures will be displayed in the datagridview when I run it?  I believe I have to convert my images to bytes, and then populate each cell individually, but I really have no clue.  I simply have a couple of .jpg's and don't know where to code or what to do.  I would greatly appreciate any light anyone could shine on this quandary of mine!!

Thanks,

Drew

Comment: You can try save the path of your stored images instead of storing the images themselves. then add custom field of type image to your gridview which ImageUrl 'll be that stored in DB

Comment: Could I just store the images in my database and then show them in datagridview?

Answer (score 0):

Check Shital's answer at [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/175339/Controls/NewControls/) link.

I would advise you not to compress stream into the database, it could choke it, depends on your database , ofcourse. What should you do is after uploading the picture, host them at you IIS and save the link address at your database record.